# Find the order of the smallest subgroup as follows

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order 2021. Let $x$ and $y$ be the elements in $G$ such that they are not equal to the identity element and of distinct order. Let $H$ be a smallest subgroup of $G$ contains $x$ and $y$. Find the order of $H$.

First I got was:

Let $|x|=m$ and $|y|=n$, where $m,n \ne 1$. Then $x^m = e_G = y^n$. How to apply the Lagrange Theorem in this to get approach?

Comment: Use prime factorization of $2021=43 \times 47$. So this is a group of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

Comment: @AnuragA Is "... this group is a group of order $pq$"  refers to $H$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $2021 = 43 \cdot 47$ and given that $x$ and $y$ are distinct and not equal to identity and by Lagrange's theorem, order of an element in $G$  must divide $2021$. If one of $x$ and $y$ has order $2021$ then we must have $H= G$.

Without loss of generality suppose we take $|x| = 47$ and $|y| = 43$. Clearly $H$ cannot have order $43$ since $x\in H$. If $H$ has order $47$ then we have $y^4 = y^4 \cdot y^{43} = y^{47} = e$ which is not possible since the order of $y$ is $43$.

Can you complete the argument?

Comment: Same idea but perhaps a bit quicker: Since $x$ and $y$ are in $H$, their orders must divide the order of $H$.

Comment: And then the order of $H$ is $2021$?

Comment: Since the order of $x$ and $y$ must divide the order of $H$ and the order of $x$ and $y$ are relative prime, then the order of $H$ is equal to the least common multiple of them. Like this?